# Setting columns variably in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

What would be the syntax for doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO table
SET 
IF *expression*
column1 = 'value1'
ELSE
column2 = 'value2'
```

Comment: Explain what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: That's the stored procedure notation for `IF`. You can't use it in a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `insert . . . select` with a `case` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2)
    select (case when *expression* then 'value1' end) as column1,
           (case when not *expression* then 'value2' end) as column2;
```

However, I suspect that you might really want an `update` and not an `insert`:

```
update table
    set column1 = (case when *expression* then 'value1' else column1 end),
        column2 = (case when not *expression* then 'value2' else column2 end);
```

Comment: Although it works, the same expression has to be evaluated twice. Is there a way to avoid such behaviour (for performance reasons)?

Comment: @user2180613 . . . Unless the expression involves a subquery, then multiple evaluation should not be an issue.  If it does, I would ask you to modify your question with the query, sample data, and expected results.  The `insert`/`update` operation is much more expensive.

Comment: Evaluations may be simple, but will be performed on several millions of rows.